# how to detect browser's "save image as" event on javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I want to detect a browser's "**save image as**" event. when someone click "**save as image**" on a image an event should occurred. Is there any event like this? or any other way to detect this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no event for that

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. When a browser displays an image, it means it already downloaded it and the data is already on the user's computer. No matter what javascript trickery you try, you will never be able to rule out the fact that whatever somebody can see, they can *always* save it and see it again (or even redistribute it elsewhere). If you don't want visitors to be able to see certain images, simply don't put them online.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to create an extension that would do this. However, it would only work for one specific browser: you'd need a Chrome extension for Chrome, a Firefox extension for Firefox, and so on.

Unfortunately there's no one-size-fits-all approach for this because it's not behavior in the website itself; it's behavior in the software of the particular web browser that's being used. Javascript can really only interact with the website.

If you explain why you want this functionality, we may be able to help you come up with a work-around!

Comment: I am guessing that the OP would like to somehow limit visitors of his web site in their ability to save his precious images. He would have really tough time convincing them to install a browser extension to help him to do so

Comment: i have a social networking website. Here users post photos so if anyone tries to download the image then a notification or message will inform that user

Comment: If you are willing /able to make this browser extension mandatory in order to use your web site - then this approach might work for you. You'll have to limit your users to certain browsers as well (very few mobile browsers support extensions)